# Which pattern should I look to for questions/answers that change?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3

I work for an organization that provides day program services to persons with developmental disabilities.  At the end of each day, workers fill out a daily log for the person or persons they worked with to record how the day went.  This information is entered into an Excel spreadsheet to enable us to do periodic reporting (i.e. quarterly).  I'd like to move this data from Excel to a database-driven website.  I'm using (learning while I go) ASP.Net MVC but my question is more general.

Each daily log is customized to each person served; all programs are unique (so each person currently has their own spreadsheet).  In addition, the fields (or questions) on the log sheets can and do change over time, as a person's program changes.  I'm currently trying to decide how to approach the domain/object model, specifically looking at a dictionary type for question/answer pairs, but the data types for all answers are not the same.  I'm thinking about maybe using Dictionary(string, object) or Dictionary(string, dynamic) (if that's possible).

Anyway, I'm starting to learn about patterns and I figure there's one or more patterns that may be the best way to go; I was hoping someone could point me towards a particular pattern(s) that you feel may be appropriate.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question is really nothing more than a block of text asking something, so I would not couple that directly to your answer. The answer is what can be "of type T", so I would use generics:

```
class Question
{
    String Text { get; set; }
}

class Answer<T>
{
    T _Answer;
    Question QuestionReference { get; set; }
    T Answer 
    {
        get { return _Answer; }
        set { if (value is T) _Answer = value; }
    }
}
```

Your database would then contain a bunch of Question entities, you would use some business logic to decide what questions to pull out for each person, and then you would create new `Answer<T>` for each question, where T is the answer's return type. You can also add validation on your answer types, and you can subclass `Question` for things like multiple choice, where the question would need to know what potential answers to display.

There are a lot of ways to represent this type of data; in the end choose what feels most comfortable to you.

Comment: Here is a similar question that has answers involving inheritance instead of generics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232363/questions-with-different-types-of-answer-in-nhibernate